# How to prove the argument's validity using rules of inference.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

If I am late for my interview, then I will not get the job. I will get the job if I interview well.
I will not interview well if I am late.
If I catch a taxi, I will not be late for my interview.
I got the job.
Therefore I caught a taxi

I know it is invalid, but how to prove and provide a counter example?

Have a look at what I did.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Correct : in order to show the invalidtiy, you have to provide a counter example*.

A counterexample is a truth assignment $v$ to the elementary sentences that satisfies all the *premises* and falsifies the *conclusion*.

Elementary sentences :

> $L =$ I am late for my interview.
>
> $J =$ I will get the job.
>
> $W =$ I interview well.
>
> $T =$ I catch a taxi.

Premises:

1) $L \to \lnot J$

2) $W \to J$

3) $L \to \lnot W$

4) $T \to \lnot L$

5) $J$

Conclusion :

6) $T$.

Thus, assume $v(T)=$ **False**.

Obviously, we want $v(J)=$ **True**, because $J$ is a premise.

With $v(T)=$ **F** we have also $v(T \to \lnot L)=$ **T** and with $v(J)=$ **T** we have $v(W \to J)=$ **T**.

Thus, up to now, we have satisfied : 2), 4) and 5).

Having $v(J)=$ **T** we can define $v(L)=$ **F** and thus also 1) is satisfied.

We are left with 3) $L \to \lnot W$. But we have $v(L)=$ **F** and thus also 1) is satisfied.

*Conclusion* : the truth assignment $v$ such that :

> $v(L)=v(T)=$ **F**  and  $v(J)=$ **T**

is the required counter example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a life saver :D

Comment: @DharmilRaval - you are welcome :-)